# ngRoute for Single Page AJAX app and Google Search indexing

Tags: ajax, angularjs, seo, ngroute

I read numerous resources on using `ngRoute html5Mode (true)` in AngularJS Single Page Applications (SPA) to facilitate Google indexing of the AJAX SPA app. I still have a following question.

**Setup:**

1. I have set up server redirection which redirects browser for URL which are not found to the root of my AngularJS app like so:

   RewriteRule ^(.*) /SPA/index.html [NC,L]
2. I also verified in Google Web Master tools that Google can access, index and correctly render individual page using direct url like this `http://braginski.com/SPA/about`
   this page is a referenced in index.html like this:

   a href="#about"

**Question:**

Now since I verified that Google bot can render my Ajax app correctly, can I just submit XML site map to Google with all URLs which I would like to index? This site map will include all URL in the conventional form (no #, no !), like so:

```
/SPA/about (full URL http://braginski.com/SPA/about)
```

Google will then index each URL (my redirection will ensure that each URL like /SPA/about is routed to root of AngularJS app for proper rednering). This way I don't have to deal with escape_fragments or any other middleware pre-rendering?

Thanks